# How to use created variables in every class?

Tags: flutter, dart, variables, widget, global-variables

I have a Widget where the user can input data like height, weight and so on in a TextFormField like this:

```
String weightText;


TextFormField(
                      initialValue: null,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      onChanged: (value) => weightText = value,
                    ),
```

Now I want to use this variable weightText in other classes. Is there another way except constructor to make the variable weightText global, so I can use it wherever i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare the variable as static in a static class. This way you can access it like this `Class.variable`

You can create a class like this :

```
class Global{
    static String weightText;
}
```

and then access the variable like this `Global.weightText`